# How to label under threshold line in barplot made in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a barplot as follows:

```
data <- data.frame(
  name=letters[1:5],
  value=sample(seq(4,15),5)
)
data
```

The data looks as follows:

```
name    value
a       5
b       6
c       14
d       15
e       7
```

I made barplots using ggplot with a line on point `10`

```
ggplot(data) +
    geom_bar( aes(x=name, y=value), stat="identity", fill="skyblue", alpha=0.7) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 10,color = "red", linetype = "solid")
```

[image]

I want to add label above as `high` and below as `low` and on `10` as `normal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use annotations:

```
ggplot(data) +
    geom_bar( aes(x=name, y=value), stat="identity", fill="skyblue", alpha=0.7) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 10,color = "red", linetype = "solid") +
    annotate("text", x = "e", y = 10.5, label = "high") +
    annotate("text", x = "e", y = 10, label = "normal") +
    annotate("text", x = "e", y = 9.5, label = "low")
```